# el contenido de un <td> rowspan=4 no abarca el 100% del <td>

Tags: html5, css3

Estoy maquetando un documento con tablas html, el problema es que quiero poner un logotipo o imagen en un `<td>` que me abarca 4 filas pero la imagen solo me toma el espacio de equivalente a una fila, aunque el `<td>` se de cuatro filas la imagen solo me toma 1, como le puedo hacer para que me tome todo el espacio del `<td>` osea el espacio de las 4 filas

este es mi codigo

```
<table class="" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

                          <tr border="2">
                              <td width="30%" rowspan="4" class="cellB">
                                <div width="100%" height="100%">
                                  <img width="100px" height="50px" src="logoo.png">
                                </div>
                              </td>
                              <td colspan="2" class="tituloPrincipal cellB" height="45px" style="background: #9ACD32; color: white;"> 
                                <center> 
                                  <div height="100%" style="margin-top:9px;">
                                    REQUISICION DE PERSONAL
                                  </div> 
                                </center>
                              </td>
                           </tr>

                           <tr>
                             <td colspan="2" class="textoT cellB" height="45px">
                              <center>
                                Para iniciar con el reclutamiento y selecci&oacute;n de personal, es necesario que la presente requisici&oacute;n se encuentre debidamente llenada y firmada
                              </center>

                             </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                             <td class="subTitulos cellB" style=""> 
                              <center>
                                FECHA DE SOLICITUD
                              </center>
                             </td>
                             <td class="subTitulos cellB"> 
                              <center>
                                FECHA DE RECEPCION
                              </center>
                             </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                             <td class="textoT cellB" style=""> 
                              <center>
                                &nbsp;28/12/2017 12:20:01
                              </center>
                             </td>
                             <td class="textoT cellB"> 
                              <center>
                                &nbsp;28/12/2017
                              </center>
                             </td>
                           </tr>


</table>
```

Comment: ¿te has fijado que la imagen tiene un ancho de 100px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías utilizar css!

Por ejemplo podrías agregar un id `#img` como el siguiente para luego aplicarselo a tu `<td>`

**CSS**

```
#img
{
  background-image: url("tuimagen");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;    
}
```

**HTML**

```
<td width="30%" rowspan="4" class="cellB" id="img"></td>
```

Espero que sea lo que buscabas!

Comment: si amigo si me funcionó, gracias